# Woocommerce Custom Child Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a page that's a child of the Shop page in WooCommerce with a permalink `http://localhost/website/shop/featured-products/`. I know the WordPress hierarchy works with `page-{slug}.php` and it'll load that first, but it doesn't work on this one (`page-featured-products.php`) because it's a child of the shop page in WooCommerce.

I also tried `page-{id}.php` but it doesn't work as well, but it all works on regular (non-woocommerce Shop child) pages.

Comment: I'd recommend installing the plugin 'Query monitor', it has a feature where it lists the template hierarchy on the current page.